# About Apache Commons EqualsBuilder and HashCodeBuilder and null values

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, apache-commons-lang

The classes [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) from the Apache Commons Lang library can be used for object comparison purposes.

E.g., one can test equality between two `Person` objects like follows:

```
Person p1 =...;
Person p2 =...;
boolean equals = new EqualsBuilder().
        append(p1.name, p2.name).
        append(p1.secondname, p2.secondname).
        append(p1.surname, p2.surname).
        append(p1.age, p2.age).
        isEquals();
```

Suppose that a field is not mandatory, e.g. `secondname`. How does EqualsBuilder and HasCodeBuilder handle this fact? Is the comparison done on this field or not? Or the comparison on a null field can be skipped as a special option?

Comment: Hey anonymous hero, please explain your downvote!

Comment: Isn't this pretty easy to test for yourself? (It would be nice if it were documented, admittedly - perhaps you could send in a patch once you've checked the behaviour.)

Comment: I understand your point

Comment: It's also easy to look at the source code to figure it out. It's free, open-source software

Answer (score 4):

These two methods will consider `p1.name` and `p2.name` to be equal if they're both null. Here's the relevant part of the freely available source code:

```
public EqualsBuilder append(Object lhs, Object rhs) {
    if (isEquals == false) {
        return this;
    }
    if (lhs == rhs) {
        return this;
    }
    ...
```